# cannot import predict from sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am getting error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'predict' from
> 'sklearn.linear_model'(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/**init**.py)

Tried everything ! Can anyone help!

Comment: Can you share the code around the area where you define and call the fit and predict methods of your model?

Comment: got it sorted, forgot to use fit function before

Comment: That's strange. When you try to predict on a non-fitted model you should get a NotFitted exception.

Answer (score 2):

`predict` is not part of the `sklearn.linear_model` module. It's a method of the linear models that are within the module. For example:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

regressor = LinearRegression()
regression.fit(X, y)
regression.predict(X)
```

Comment: using it for ,     s = ridge.predict(Xtrain)